# Resize JPanel within a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

So I have a `JPanel` which is added to a `JFrame`.

The `JPanel` includes a large graphic, and the main part that I wish to display is `800 x 400` pixels.

There is extra on either sides, which doesn't matter.

When I resize the `JFrame` which contains the inner `JPanel`, is there a way to resize the `JPanel` as well so that those important pixels are still shown?

Here's what I tried:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simon");
Renderer renderer = new Renderer(); //this object extends JPanel, which is what i'm adding to the frame

frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
frame.setResizable(true);
renderer.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT)); //want to keep it centered on this width/height because there is important content within there.
frame.add(renderer, BorderLayout.CENTER);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

This is not doing anything different to it than normal.

Any advice?

Edit: Adding the renderer class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Renderer extends JPanel
{

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see javax.swing.JComponent#paintComponent(java.awt.Graphics)
     */
    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);    
        Simon.simon.paint((Graphics2D) g); //Simon is the first class that holds the code all the way above
    }   
}
```

Comment: why are you setting preferredSize? If you remove that line what happens?

Comment: You have to give us your RenderClass as well because it works just fine when changing the type of renderer to a JPanel

Comment: Normally, when using `BorderLayout.CENTER`, your JPanel resizes itself automatically. [You may also want to read this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7229226/should-i-avoid-the-use-of-setpreferredmaximumminimumsize-methods-in-java-swi)

Comment: @OliverWatkins, when I remove setPreferredSize, the JFrame becomes 0 x 0 pixels for some reason (or whatever the smallest possible size is).

Comment: @Raven, added the Renderer class. Thanks.

Comment: are you sure? frame.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT); should work fine. Depending if your width and height are the values you want

Comment: @YassinHajaj, the thing is, the stuff I am painting is bigger than the WIDTH and HEIGHT already.

Comment: what happens with frame.setSize(300,300)?

Comment: @OliverWatkins, yes I am sure. Not sure why, but it is acting like that.

Comment: @OliverWatkins, same thing occurs.

Comment: ok, gotta catch a bus. i can have another look tomorrow

Comment: @OliverWatkins, ahh that is happening because of frame.pack(); just figured it out

Comment: give me your Simon code as well

Comment: can you put your answer in the answer section to help other people out?

Comment: Yeah, i got the same problem